# How to get gridded data in Excel into ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel

I am very new to using ArcGIS. Right now I have an Excel sheet with data in it where each cell represents a grid from a model output and contains a value (eg. amount of precipitation in that grid cell from the model output). I am given the coordinates for the "corners" of this area and that each grid box has a lat-lon of 1/16 degree. So the data is already "spatially" laid out in excel. Is there a straightforward way to import this type of data format directly into ArcGIS while maintaining the spatial layout of the data?

Comment: Your best route is probably to insert the rows which would make the Excel format correspond to [ASCII grid format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid), and then save the whole tab to ASCII, which would then allow conversion to GeoTIFF or some other GIS raster format.

Comment: I was going to say pretty much the same thing. I think you would also need to know the number of rows and columns but if they are already arranged that way in the spreadsheet, then you are good. http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following.

1. Save the Spreadsheet as a csv file.
2. Open the csv in a text editor, and search/replace the commas for nothing (just leave a single space).
3. Add the rest of the information to the header of the file above the values. Watch for the word wrapping as noted in the comment below.

   ncols 480
   nrows 450
   xllcorner -82.34552
   yllcorner 36.99842
   cellsize **0.0625**
   nodata_value -32768

Note that you can use corner or center (the data above uses corner) of the lower left cell. I think the difficult part of this is going to be working with units of **degrees** (but I could be wrong). I just say this because they vary across latitude but I'm guessing with a raster it just makes them all one size like a projected coordinate system?

If that all works you should be able to bring the ASCII grid in and convert it to a raster format.

Comment: Most stock text editors are going to default to word-wrap where, the lines wrap to a new line after a certain column width. Make sure to turn this off before opening the ASCII flat file otherwise, the data will become corrupted.

Comment: The last time I used this format was back at 8. *something*, but the documentation says that the reader will ignore newlines, so a split would only corrupt if it was in the *middle* of a value.